# Skip iterations in a do-loop (fortran)

Tags: fortran, iteration, fortran90, do-loops

I want to loop over N iterations, but some of the iterations should be "skipped" under particular conditions. 
I know I can do it using the `goto` statement, such as :

```
       do i = 1, N
          if condition(i) goto 14
          ! Execute my iteration if condition(i) is false
    14    continue
       end do
```

But I am a little scared of these `goto` statements, and I would like to know if there is another solution (I am using fortran 90 but would be interested in any solution, even if it requires a newer version).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
do i = 1, N
          if (condition(i)) cycle
          ! Execute my iteration if condition(i) is false
end do
```

If you need explanation, comment on what you need clarification of.  Note I've dropped the archaic `continue` and labelled statement.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I had seen this `cycle` statement but misunderstood the reference I found about it : I thought it would basically exit the loop without doing the remaining iterations. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can also to this:

```
   do i = 1, N
      if ( .not. condition(i) ) then
         ! Execute my iteration if condition(i) is false
      endif
   end do
```

Comment: It's the most obvious indeed, but I was trying to use something less heavy in terms of indentation/writing of the code.

Since `condition(i)` is rarely `true`, it seemed more "readable" to write it using the `cycle` function.